# 2D игры на Андроид

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Хочу выучить *Android* и, как описано [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164853/), мне, во-первых, надо знать *JAVA*. 
Я не против *JAVA* и понимаю что этот язык стоит на вершине как *C#* , *C++* и т.д. 
Но особо хочу написать 2D-игру (типа [этой](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aa.generaladaptiveapps&hl=ru)) на *Андроид*.
Скачал *Андроид Студио* но, как понимаю, с ним создать игру не так уж легко, как программу.
Жду советы професионалов в этой сфере:
1. **Какие библиотеки и 2D движки мне надо знать**?
2. **Какие языки предпочетаемы для Андроид кроме *JAVA***

Comment: спасибо за правку @alexander barakin :)

Comment: вопрос состоит из 2х вопросов, думаю нужно было создать 2 вопроса для каждого

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для создания игр у вас 2 пути:

1 - Использовать какой-то игровой движок/framework.

2 - Изучать openGL.

Идею о том чтобы пытаться рисовать объекты используя `canvas.drawBitmap()` отбрасывайте сразу -  потому что это тупиковый путь на который просто можно убить время и не получить достойного результата.

Путь 1 Движки.

Одни из самых популярных - Unity - по нему куча уроков + сообщество + бесплатные и платные плагины ассеты. Минусы - немного громоздкий, но бесспорно мощный и лидирующий в отрасли.

Если хочется больше классического программирования и небольших приложений, я бы советовал обратить внимание на framework/движок libgdx, подключается к проекту элементарно, весит мало, большое сообщество, много уроков, легко начать делать простенькие спрайтовые игрушки.
вот уроки по быстрому старту от Survitruf (кстати сам Survitruf сейчас пересел на Unity).
http://suvitruf.ru/libgdx/
Обзорно по другим движкам можно посмотреть тут:
http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=315915

Путь 2. Изучать openGL самому не сказать чтоб очень легкий путь. Во первых сложно найти рускоязычный материал, а если и находится, то он очень устаревший годов 2005,2006 и так сейчас уже никто не делает работает.
Можно попробовать с уроков usnavii на 4pda они актуальны, есть примеры спрайтовой анимации, работы с текстурными атласами, системами частиц.
http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=418429
 Путь долгий, сложный, но если происходит просветление и понимание что к чему, вы становитесь независимы от движков, можете легко делать простые 2d и 3d игры не загромождая их ненужными возможностями движков, делать более легкие и более быстрые приложения.

Answer (score 1):

по поводу 2D я не знаю, но кроме java есть технологии

1. [Embarcadero® RAD Studio™](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio)  котором можно программировать на `Pascal/Delphi` и `C++`
2. [Ionic](http://ionic.io/) создание мобильных приложения на `HTML`/`CSS`/`JS`
3. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) создание мобильных приложения на `HTML`/`CSS`/`JS`

Comment: Спасибо за информацию )

Comment: Для игр вам понадобиться Cocos2d. Что бы добавить физику - Box2d. Они обычно идут в паре Cocos2d+Box2d и никаких шаманств